# Using EasyMock with recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, mocking, easymock

I am using a series of Strict Mocks generated with EasyMock 3.2 to test a method that call's itself recursively. By setting the expectations of my mocks I can control the method so that it only calls itself once and then exits. However, I am seeing some very strange behaviour from EasyMock which looks like a bug, where it get's confused about the number of times a method is expected.

For example:

```
final Collection srcCollection = EasyMock.createStrictMock(Collection.class);
final NativeBroker broker = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(NativeBroker.class)
    .addMockedMethod("getCollection")
    .addMockedMethod("getSubject")
    .createStrictMock();

expect(srcCollection.getURI()).andReturn(src);

replay(srcCollection, broker);

//run the test
broker.checkPermissionsForCopy(srcCollection, dest, newName);

verify(srcCollection, broker);
```

Leads to the error from EasyMock:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Expectation failure on verify:
        Collection.getURI(): expected: 2, actual: 1
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.verify(MocksControl.java:226)
        at org.easymock.EasyMock.verify(EasyMock.java:2080)
```

I have only instructed EasyMock to expect one result, so why does it think I want two? I also get the same error if I change my expectation to this:

```
expect(srcCollection.getURI()).andReturn(src).once();
```

...And it get's stranger...

If I change my expectation to this:

```
expect(srcCollection.getURI()).andReturn(src).times(2);
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Expectation failure on verify:
        Collection.getURI(): expected: 3, actual: 1
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.verify(MocksControl.java:226)
        at org.easymock.EasyMock.verify(EasyMock.java:2080)
```

And, further if I change my expectation to this:

```
expect(srcCollection.getURI()).andReturn(src).anyTimes();
```

I get an even stranger error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: last method called on mock already has a non-fixed count set.
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.replay(MocksControl.java:216)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(EasyMock.java:2012)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, or know of any limitations with EasyMock in recursive functions?

Comment: this is a guess, but try changing `replay(srcCollection, broker);` to `replay(srcCollection);`

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your `getURI` method.
Also, be sure you don't need to mock any other methods within your NativeBroker class.

Comment: @Jason If I do not replay `broker` then my expectations for `getCollection` and `getSubject` on the partial mock fail.

Comment: @DanTemple the method under test is here - https://github.com/adamretter/exist/blob/develop/src/org/exist/storage/NativeBroker.java#L998
In my local clone, I have removed the `final` so that it is testable with EasyMock. The getURI() calls occur from within that method.

Comment: @adamretter The fact that `checkPermissionsForCopy` is final should not cause you problems as you're not mocking that method. The `getURI` method is not final either and nor is the Collection class, so you're not missing anything there. I imagine the root of your problem is that you have no expectations for the `NativeBroker`. Adding the methods as mocked means that you are able to add expectations for them, but you have provided none. I imagine default behaviour is happening (returning null) and thus `checkPermissionsForCopy` is not following the path you expect.

Comment: @DanTemple, sorry there are actually expectations on the Broker, I tried to simplify the code I posted as it is rather long. My complete  test case that has the problem is here - https://github.com/adamretter/exist/blob/feature/fix-inherited-perms/test/src/org/exist/storage/NativeBrokerTest.java#L226

In particular the issue that I seem to see and described above is at line 276.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I repeated same expected values 2 times. And it throws:

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: last method called on mock already has a non-fixed count set.*

**E.G.**

```
SchedulingDataForVersion dataForVersion = createNiceMock(SchedulingDataForVersion.class);
TaskSource mockedTaskSource = createNiceMock(TaskSource.class);

    expect(mockedTaskSource.getOrderElement()).andReturn(orderLine).anyTimes();
    expect(mockedTaskSource.getOrderElement()).andReturn(orderLine).anyTimes();

    replay(dataForVersion, mockedTaskSource);
```

**Correct** one is:

```
SchedulingDataForVersion dataForVersion = createNiceMock(SchedulingDataForVersion.class);
TaskSource mockedTaskSource = createNiceMock(TaskSource.class);

    expect(dataForVersion.getOrderElement()).andReturn(orderLine).anyTimes();
    expect(mockedTaskSource.getOrderElement()).andReturn(orderLine).anyTimes();

    replay(dataForVersion, mockedTaskSource
```

Comment: Received the same error and this checked out - make sure you're not "expecting" the same same call twice. I was editing a unit test and didn't realize something was mocked before it.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs when you add `.anyTimes()` and then you write the same call.

`expect(mock.get()).andReturn("string").anyTimes();`  --> first call with multiple support
`expect(mock.get()).andReturn("string");` --> second call not needed

The solution is to write only the first call with multiple support

`expect(mock.get()).andReturn("string").anyTimes();`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with this code.

Are the two mocked methods on the broker expected not to be called?

I made a test case. Can you make it fail?

```
public class AppTest {

public static interface Collection {
    String getURI();
}

public static class NativeBroker {

    public void checkPermissionsForCopy(Collection srcCollection, String dest,
            String newName) {
        srcCollection.getURI();
    }

    public Collection getCollection() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return null;
    }
}

String src = "http://src.com";
String dest = "http://dest.com";
String newName = "my name";

@Test
public void testApp() {
    final Collection srcCollection = EasyMock.createStrictMock(Collection.class);
    final NativeBroker broker = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(NativeBroker.class)
            .addMockedMethod("getCollection")
            .addMockedMethod("getSubject")
            .createStrictMock();

    expect(srcCollection.getURI()).andReturn(src);

    replay(srcCollection, broker);

    // run the test
    broker.checkPermissionsForCopy(srcCollection, dest, newName);

    verify(srcCollection, broker);
}}
```

Comment: The two methods on the broker are expected to be called, I just omitted them from my initial post for brevity. The test case can be found here: https://github.com/adamretter/exist/blob/feature/fix-inherited-perms/test/src/org/exist/storage/NativeBrokerTest.java#L226